# Pgfplots: Show error marker in legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is there a way to include an error bar (and possibly the error markers, although I don't need that in my current usecase) with the marker symbol in the legend?

---

(The specific reason I want this is the volume of the data: my scatterplot contains very many (~1000-5000) points. Therefore I colour the error bars/markers in a light gray so the points are not obscured in a large cloud of error markers of the same colour. Now I'd be nice for the gray error bar to show up in the legend.)

I tried adding just a gray solid line below the marker with `\addlegendimage{...}` but couldn't make it work.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    legend entries={Something},
  ]
  \addplot [
    only marks,
    error bars/.cd,
      y dir=both, y explicit,
      error bar style={color=gray},
    ] 
    coordinates {
      (0, 0) +- (0, .5)
      (0.5, 0.5) +- (0, .5)
      (1, 1) +- (0, .7)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**: Andrew Swann's initial answer (although it is not exactly what I had in mind when asking this question) provides a nice legend. More importantly, it gave me enough hints about the implementation of legend images to realize that it might be feasible changing.

Based on his revised answer, I'm now using

```
\doccumentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\pgfplotsset{error bar legend/.style={%
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.prefix code={%
      \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}{\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
      \draw[%
        /pgfplots/every error bar, 
        mark=\pgfplotserrorbarsmark, 
        /pgfplots/error bars/error mark options, 
        sharp plot,
        ##1
      ] plot coordinates {(0.3cm, -0.15cm) (0.3cm, 0.15cm)};%
      %\pgfkeysalso{%
        %/pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar={(0.3cm, 0cm)}{(0.3cm, 0.15cm)},
        %/pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar={(0.3cm, 0cm)}{(0.3cm, -0.15cm)},
      %};
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    legend entries={Something},
  ]
  \addplot [
    only marks,
    error bar legend,
    error bars/.cd,
      y dir=both, y explicit,
      error bar style={color=gray},
    ] 
    coordinates {
      (0, 0) +- (0, .5)
      (0.5, 0.5) +- (0, .5)
      (1, 1) +- (0, .7)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `/draw error bar` (now commented) suffers from <del>two</del> one thing<del>s</del>, I still don't know why, though:

- <del>the error bar style is not being applied (i.e. the bar is not gray)</del> that was actually due to a typo (and I failed to see the error message) and apparently due to not wrapping things in a scope
- the marks are asymmetric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\addlegendimage` needs to be followed by `\addlegendentry`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [
    only marks,
    error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    error bar style={color=gray},
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0, 0) +- (0, .5)
    (0.5, 0.5) +- (0, .5)
    (1, 1) +- (0, .7)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Something}
    \addlegendimage{color=gray,mark=|,
    mark options={mark repeat=2,mark phase=1}}
    \addlegendentry{Error bar}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The arguments to `\addlegendimage` are style options.  I have used them to set the colour and to make the legend image look like an error bar by using the vertical marker.  As the bar is drawn as the plot of three coordinates, you get the mark on the first and last places by specifying the repeat to be `2` starting at (`phase`) the first node.  Standard settings are repeat of `2` but phase `2` meaning the marker is only plotted in the middle.

To print the error bar as part of the first legend entry, you can adjust the `legend image code` as follows:

```
legend image code/.code={
        \draw[sharp plot,mark=-,mark repeat=2,mark phase=1,color=gray,##1]
        plot coordinates { (0.3cm, -0.15cm) (0.3cm,0cm) (0.3cm, 0.15cm) };%
        \draw[mark repeat=2,mark phase=2,##1]
        plot coordinates {(0cm,0cm) (0.3cm,0cm) (0.6cm,0cm)};%
        }
```

The second of these two draw commands is the default for a the legend; the first adds a vertical line with marks at its ends.  Drawing in this order ensures that the main mark covers the line in the middle.

[image: Sample with bar]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/error bar legend/.style={
    legend image code/.code={
        \draw[sharp plot,mark=-,mark repeat=2,mark phase=1,color=gray,##1]
        plot coordinates { (0.3cm, -0.15cm) (0.3cm,0cm) (0.3cm, 0.15cm) };%
        \draw[mark repeat=2,mark phase=2,##1]
        plot coordinates {(0cm,0cm) (0.3cm,0cm) (0.6cm,0cm)};%
        }}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    legend entries={Something},
    ]
    \addplot [
    only marks,
    error bar legend,
    error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    error bar style={color=gray},
    ]
    coordinates {
      (0, 0) +- (0, .5)
      (0.5, 0.5) +- (0, .5)
      (1, 1) +- (0, .7)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oups, I failed to mention that I did use it with `\addlegendentry`. Thanks for the pointers, I updated my question reflecting your suggestions.

Comment: @Wisperwind OK, I have posted a second version with this styling

Comment: Manually `\draw`ing the paths does the trick, thanks again! I changed the code a little to obtain the error bar style from the keys in `/pgfplots/error bars/`, I'll edit my question accordingly.

Do you have a clue as to why `\draw error bar` results in asymmetric marks?

Comment: @Wisperwind Yes, grabbing some info from the `error bar` styles is a good idea.  Why your method gives asymmetric marks is unclear to me; it looks as if some spaces are leaking in to the code, but commenting out all obvious candidates does not seem to help.

Comment: Well, it's not that important, the current solution is sufficiently clean since it picks up (hopefully) all of the `error bar` styles.